# What function to use to show one to one correspondence?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

This problem is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

Here's an example problem that the author gave
[image]

I'am working on problem 2e. I first recognized the set as countably infinite. If you do the Cartesian product of A with some zs say a portion of it, {1,2,3}, you get coordinates {(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)...} and so on which are countable and keep going(because the set of integers keeps going on. My question is what function to use to show the one to one correspondence between the set of positive integers and this set(Cartesian product of A and z+. set of positive integers)? I have a hard time with coming up with some function that will map a positive integer to a member of this set. The example problem's function was pretty intuitive. If you have a positive integer, to map to a odd positive integer, have a function like f(n) = 2n -1, or multiply it by 2 and subtract 1. What about this case?

Comment: You could map the even integers to {(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)...} and the odd integers to {(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)...}.

Comment: so no simple function like for odd integers - f(n) = 2n - 1?

Comment: You don't need to have a simple function; the kind of thing David has in his answer is perfectly fine. But in this particular case, it's not too hard to come up with a simple function for the reverse mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ be

$$f(n) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{n+1}{2} & n \ \text{ is odd}\\ -\dfrac{n}{2} & n \ \text{ is even}\end{cases}$$

Then define $g:\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}\to A\times \mathbb Z^+$ as

$$g(n) = \begin{cases}\{2\}\times \{-n\} &: n <0\\ \{3\}\times \{n\} &: n >0\end{cases}$$

$f$ and $g$ are both bijections. So $g\circ f$ is also a bijection.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20407/discussion-on-answer-by-david-what-function-to-use-to-show-one-to-one-correspond).

Comment: It's harder to read in chat - all the symbols and stuff. I think it's better if there are just a few comments and give the reader the option to see more. Can you move it back?

Comment: David, did you do a separate proof to prove this? So g∘f is also a bijection? Or is this some known property?

Comment: No, I did not explicitly prove it, but if you go through the motions it should be clear.

Comment: What do you mean by motions ?

Comment: "Going though the motions" is an idiom for busywork. After you do hundreds of similar problems the pencil almost writes the proof for you. It is very easy to show $f$ and $g$ are both bijections, just takes writing it down. You can even see that the composition is just $g\circ f(n) = \{3\} \times\{(n+1)/2\}$ if $n$ is odd, $g\circ f(n) = \{2\} \times \{n/2\}$ if $n$ is even. Then $g\circ f(2k+1)=\{2\}\times\{k\}$ and $g\circ f(2k)=\{3\}\times\{k\}$

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple function that maps the tuples in $\{2, 3\}\times \mathbb Z^+$ to the positive integers.

Let $(t_0, t_1)$ be a member of $\{2, 3\}\times \mathbb Z^+$

Then $(t_0 - 2)(2t_1 - 1) - (t_0 - 3)(2t_1)$ maps each $(t_0, t_1)$ to a unique member of $\mathbb Z^+$

If $t_0 = 2$ the 1st term vanishes and we get $-(-1)(2t_1)$ = $2t_1$

If $t_1 = 3$ the 2nd term vanishes and we get $(1)(2t_1 - 1)$ = $2t_1 - 1$

So we've mapped tuples of the form $(2, t_1)$ to even numbers and tuples of the form $(3, t_1)$ to odd numbers.

Inverting this function will be left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: ummm where did you get  (t0−2)(2t1−1)−(t0−3)(2t1) ?

Comment: @committedandroider: I just made it up, using an old programming trick to do stuff like this without using an `if` statement. :) I wanted a two-term function such that one term maps to the odd numbers & the other term maps to the even numbers, hence the factors $(2t_1−1)$ & $(2t_1)$. The $(t_0−2)$ and $-(t_0−3)$ factors act as binary switches: if $t_0=3$ then $(t_0−2)=1$ and $-(t_0−3)=0$; if $t_0=2$ then $(t_0−2)=0$ and $-(t_0−3)=1$. Does that help?